# Does in-app purchases work in offline mode?

Tags: ios, connection, in-app-purchase, offline

I suppose that it's not so common case when user's device is without internet connection. But let's imagine this situation:

- no wifi
- cellular data is off

Does in-app purchases works in this circumstances ?

Are there any error handling which covers this situations(check if there is a connection/if there is no connection- throw an error), when implementing in-app purchases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In-app purchase need internet connection to communicate with apple server.
You can handle internet connection state with https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: So what would be preferred way to handle this? To hide buttons for in-app purchases and show a message : "Check your internet connection" or something in similar manner?

Comment: you can show an alert. or hide the button where user can buy.